# IF/ELSE statement in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

Can anyone advice regarding this `if` statement?

```
hour=`date "+%k"`
echo $hour
if [ $hour > 7 ] && [ $hour < 21 ]; then
    cd /bill/bscs/SCRIPTS/SMS
    sms_not.csh samples.lst "New file has arrived"
else
    cd /bill/bscs/SCRIPTS/SMS
    sms_not.csh basicList.lst "New file has arrived"
fi
```

In short, the script is supposed to send an SMS to a certain group if the hour requirement is met; if not, it will send it to the other group.

The `$hour` variable is correct, I can see it with `echo $hour`, but for some reason it always executes, whatever comes after the else.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: I've edited your question. Code should be formatted by indenting it 4 spaces or clicking the `{}` icon; a leading `>` is for formatting unformatted text. And proper capitalization makes your text easier to read.

Comment: point taken , thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `BASH` you can use `((...))` for arithmetic expressions:

```
if (( hour > 7 && hour < 21 )); then
   cd /bill/bscs/SCRIPTS/SMS
   sms_not.csh samples.lst "New file has arrived"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have seen some error messages.

For the correct syntax of the operators, see: `man test`

`<` is `-lt`, and `>` is `-gt`.

Note: clean up the files you've created (`7`, and if you haven't seen an error message, `21` as well)

Comment: There may not be an error message, since I/O redirections are processed and removed prior to argument parsing. `[ $hour > 7 ]` is equivalent to `[ $hour ] > 7`, so `[` is getting two arguments, the expansion of `$hour` and `]`, after the shell opens the file `7` for the standard output of `[`.

Comment: @chepner: `< 21` should still yield an error (that's why I made a distinction in the note).

Comment: Ah, yes, since it needs to pre-exist in order to open for input.

Answer (score 3):

The correct statement is

```
if [ "$hour" -gt 7 ] && [ "$hour" -lt 21 ];
```

With the `[` command, you need to quote parameter expansions to guard against unset or empty variables, and you must use `-gt` and `-lt` for integer comparisons. (Even for string comparisons, you would need to quote `<` and `>` to prevent them from being treated as redirection operators. For example:

```
if [ "$string" \> "cat" ]; then
```